# jQuery Validation Additional method for checking image width and height: error message is always shown

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I just implemented a [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) Additional method for checking a minimum image width and height, here is the code:

```
$.validator.addMethod('imagedim', function(value, element, params) {
    // optional element
    if (this.optional(element)) {
        return true;
    }

  var _URL = window.URL;
  var img;
  if ((el = element.files[0])) {
    img = new Image();
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(el);
    img.onload = function() {
      if (this.width < params[0] || this.height < params[1]) {
        console.log("Width:" + this.width + ",  Height: " + this.height);
        return false;   
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    };
  }
}, ("Please upload images bigger than {0}x{1}"));
```

The problem is that the error message shows up for every picture size, it seems to return always `false`.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dc0myLr4/1/) showing the behavior: it doesn't matter if you try to upload small, big or huge pictures, the error message is always shown.

I'm not expert in JS and I'm sure that I am wrong in something, but I can'0t see where...

Thank you

Comment: Dig a little deeper to see *why* the method is always failing.  As per your jsFiddle, no matter what size JPG I select, your `console.log` message always reports `Width:350, Height:213`... time to figure out why.

Comment: Thanks: I haven't this problem (width and height of uploaded image are right), but I noticed that in Firebug the message is logged twice, and have no idea why...

Comment: I can't get your code to work, but I'm nearly certain that you do not want to use `this` after you've defined `img = new Image()`.  Use `img.width` and `img.height` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue while checking dimension of image as image loading is asynchronous .
"IMG load function will execute only after your image is completely loaded by the browser and since its asynchronous your function will not wait for it to execute"

I used following approach. Hope it will help.

Set one extra attribute in image tag while on change of file like below

```
$('input[type=file]').on('change',function(){
    element = $(this);
    var files = this.files;
    var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var image, file;
    image = new Image();
    image.src = _URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
        image.onload = function() {
            element.attr('uploadWidth',this.width);
            element.attr('uploadHeigth',this.width);
        }
    });
```

and now you can modify your function to below

```
$.validator.addMethod('checkDim', function (value, element, param) {     
    var image = new Image();
    var file = element.files[0];
    var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    image.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
        if(element.uploadWidth== param[0] element.uploadHeigth== param[1]){ 
            return true;
        }
        else{            
            return false;
        }

}, 'Image dimension must be as specified');
```